# pass query with parameter to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Univ(short id) {

        var db = new DbEntities();

        var query = from u in db.Universitates
                     join f in db.Facultates on u.IDUniv equals f.IDUniv
                     join s in db.Specializares on f.IDFac equals s.IDFac
                     where u.IDUniv == id
                     select new SearchViewModel
                     {
                         NumeUniv = u.NumeUniv,
                         OrasUniv = u.OrasUniv,
                         IDUniv = u.IDUniv,
                         NumeFac = f.NumeFac,
                         NumeSpec = s.NumeSpec
                     };

        return View(query);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Proj.Models.SearchViewModel

<h3>@Model.NumeUniv</h3>
```

I have the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Proj.Models.SearchViewModel]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Proj.Models.SearchViewModel'.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is returning a enumerable list of `SearchViewModel` while your view is only looking for a single `SearchViewModel`.

Please try `return View(query.First());`